# Ошибка в отправке багов в телеграмм боте (telebot)

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

Я не могу понять, почему я не могу отправить себе в группу отчет об ошибке (не ругайтесь за плохой код, работаю с библиотекой в первый раз). Язык Python.
Код: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TJtYHThE7xyBZ2Z0e0oKJg4bklk2L-Fi/view?usp=sharing
(в файле config.py хранятся настройки)
А именно не понятен данный блок кода

```
def register_final_step(message):
    try:
        chat_id = message.chat.id
        user = config.user_dict[chat_id]
        user.bugtime = int (message.text)

        # ЗАЯВКА ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЮ
        bot.send_message(chat_id, getRegData(user, 'Ваша заявка', message.from_user.first_name), parse_mode="Markdown")
        # ЗАЯВКА В ГРУППУ
        bot.send_message(config.bug_group_id, getRegData(user, 'Заявка от бота', bot.get_me().username), parse_mode="Markdown")
    except Exception as e:
        bot.send_message (message.chat.id, 'Кажется, произошла ошибка... Свяжитесь с разработчиком и передайте ему код ошибки (Код ошибки: 3)')
# формирует вид заявки регистрации
# нельзя делать перенос строки Template
# в send_message должно стоять parse_mode="Markdown"
def getRegData(user, title, name):
    t = Template('$title *$name* \n Тип ошибки: *$userBugtype* \n Время: *$Bugtime*')

    return t.substitute({
        'title': title,
        'name': name,
        'Bugtype': user.Bugtype,
        'bugtime': user.bugtime,
    })
```

В телеграмме выводится ошибка 3

[image: Пример]

Как можно это исправить?

Comment: `user.bugtime = int (message.text)` - если не выходит текст сообщения преобразовать в `int` получите `exeption`, а они у вас все обрабатываются одинаково

Comment: Второе - в `Template` у вас `*$Bugtime*` а в `substitute` - `'bugtime': user.bugtime`